# How to parse JSON string to tweepy.Status object?

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I want to store data about tweets in the database in raw format and figured out that you can pull out the jsob from `tweepy.Status` for this purpose like this:

`status._json`

How can I parse `json` back to the `tweepy.Status` object?

Answer (score 4):

I've found non-elegant solution for my problem. All you need is that:

`tweepy.Status().parse(None, status_json)`

where `None` should be `tweepy.api.API` object, but it not nedeed for parsing at all.

You can also compare the result with the original status for self-check. In my case this has `True` result:

`tweepy.Status().parse(None, status_json) == status`

Answer (score 4):

Here you go! It took me forever to get this going! This gets all info out of the status object.

all_tweets_loaded is the tweepy.Status object

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
dfflat = pd.DataFrame()
for tweet in all_tweets_loaded:
    df_for_tweet = json_normalize(tweet._json)
    dfflat=dfflat.append(df_for_tweet,ignore_index=True,sort=True)
```

dfflat.columns.tolist() #TO TEST IT HAS ALL THE COLUMNS

Comment: Hey Tuyo, if you have an update or edit for your answer, you should put it in the actual answer, not a comment.

Comment: You made my day ! Perfect , I was just searching all the day to do this!